# How to migrate private Verdaccio npm registry to another server?

Tags: node.js, npm, verdaccio

I'm planning to setup private npm registry for our internal Node.js/web projects, and seems that [Verdaccio](https://verdaccio.org/) is the best open-source choice for it.

Before starting to publish my private packages there I want to be sure that an easy way to move Verdaccio installation with all published packages to another server exists. [Here](https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia/issues/419) is a similar question for [Sinopia](https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia) Verdaccio project is forked from. Folks there say that we should simply move entire `sinopia` directory to another server. But what is the exact directory and what is the directory (or, probably, few directories) for Verdaccio?

I have Node.js installed by [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) script and Verdaccio installed globally the following way:

```sh
npm install -g verdaccio
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here Verdaccio core maintainer. Not long time ago I've written down the required steps to move from latest Sinopia to any Verdaccio (v3,v4-alpha).

In a nutshell (for UNIX):

1. The folder `~/.local/share/sinopia` must be renamed to `~/.local/share/verdaccio`
2. The folder `~/.config/sinopia` must be renamed to `~/.config/verdaccio`

There is an additional step, not required, but recommended:

3. The file `~/.config/sinopia/storage/.sinopia-db.json` must be renamed to `~/.local/share/verdaccio/storage/.verdaccio-db.json`

To find the Windows location, [check the following link](https://verdaccio.org/docs/en/cli#default-storage-location).

I hope this helps. Original source in the link below.

https://verdaccio.org/blog/2019/02/24/migrating-verdaccio#migrating-from-sinopia-140-to-verdaccio-2x-3x

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very helpful. To summarize, one have to move `~/.local/share/verdaccio` and `~/.config/verdaccio` directories to a new server after Verdaccio installation. I believe it would be better to include these essential notes in your answer.

Comment: There is a new tool that can help with this, https://github.com/rluvaton/bulk-npm-publish